# Рандомно вылетает Wordpress на страницу install.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

При работе с wordpress в абсолютно случайный момент берет и вылетает wp на страницу install.php и в се работа уходит в никуда, при попытке вписать какие-то данные в поля вылетает очень много строк ошибок, ничего не могу с этим сделать помогите
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забудьте про этот хостинг, ищите другой.

Answer (score 0):

Может отправлять на install , когда не получает данных с обязательных таблиц из Wordpress. Видимо на хостинге какие-то проблемы с подключением к базе. Решить проблему можно только через поддержку хостинга , либо сменить хостинг.

Comment: Да у них там на хостинге стоит max_queries_per_hour. Ничем они не помогут. С таким хостингом не о чем разговаривать.

Comment: Может апгрейд тарифа сделают . Видимо тариф хостинга не соответствует нагрузкам на сайте

Comment: да какие нагрузки, если он только начинает создавать сайт

Comment: Тогда менять хост либо ограниченно пользоваться сайтом с лимитом запросов в 15к в час

Comment: Ахаха, я и не заметил. В самом деле, 15к в час. Это настолько смехотворно, что ответ один - бегом с этого хостинга! Накидав кучу плагинов вместе с WooCommerce, легко получить 3000 запросов за одну загрузку страницы. Весь лимит будет израсходован за 5 обновлений страницы. А мне доводилось видеть и 26 тыс запросов при одной загрузке страницы, правда, то был совсем клинический случай.